# Can actually $2+2=5$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, modular-arithmetic, arithmetic

Now before you downvote me, I just want to say that this is a legit question I have right now and considering that in recent debates sparking around on the Internet, I want to know whether there is some truth behind this.

I couldn't find anything though, except that somebody referred me to modular arithmetic. But I don't quite understand what he meant by that. So, does modular arithmetic actually allow an operation like $2+2=5$? If that's the case, wouldn't that mean that $2$ is a completely different concept in modular arithmetic?

I also tried searching the question here, and no find. So, I am sorry if this question has been already discussed here already.

Comment: Can a cat be a dog ?

Comment: If 4=5 then 0=1. So not in any good algebraic structure is $2+2=5$. One can have $2+2=1$ though, if $3=0$.

Comment: If the premise that $1+1=3$ then $2+2=5$ is true.

Comment: Sure, $2+2=5 \mod 1$.

Comment: It won't work for modular-arithmetic as well except $\pmod 1$ which is problematic in definition. If you accept the definition then it would mean $2+2$ and $5$ are both multiple of $1$ in that sense.

Comment: Well, we do have 2+2=0 in nimbers.

Comment: @TheSilverDoe cat$\equiv$dog$\pmod{\text{carnivora}}$.

Comment: @Yourong'DZR'Zang Do not insult my dog, please.

Comment: @TheSilverDoe Uhm yeah, no. You totally missed the point of the question. But not that much of an issue anyway anymore since somebody actually did answer it properly instead of ridiculing the question. So, yeah, 2 + 2 can actually be 5, in a different system. Whether it makes sense or not is totally up for debate and I would disagree with such a definition like 2 + 2 = 5, sure. But again, that wasn't my question. Please read the question next time before commenting. Thank you.

Comment: @Tetragrammaton A cat can be a dog in a different system.

Comment: @TheSilverDoe You still don't seem to understand that you're comparing apples and oranges here. But well, if we are strict, then yes, a cat could definitely be a dog in a different system/nomenclature, especially if we change the definitions of both terms and switch them. You also seem to confuse mathematics with something that has to be real. That's now what mathematics is. There are enough mathematical concepts that are very counter-intuitive. Also, the example by justadzr is the thing you're most likely looking for.

Comment: @Tetragrammaton You are right, but actually, an apple *can be* an orange in a different system.

Comment: @TheSilverDoe That's correct. A similar example to what justadz posted: $apple \equiv orange ~(mod fruit)$

Comment: @Tetragrammaton I see, but what if in a different system, "correct" *can be* "incorrect" ?...

Comment: @TheSilverDoe Then they've just swapped their definitions. If the word "correct" now means incorrect, then "incorrect" now means correct. It's all just definitions in the end. I found another good answer that shows how 2 + 2 = 5 in abstract algebra by defining a new operation. https://www.quora.com/How-can-we-make-2+2-5-1/answer/Gabriel-Phillips-16 (Enjoy and learn) Of course, in the integer system, in standard arithmetics, 2+2 will always be 4. Nobody disputed that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Modular Arithmetic arises from the concept of **congruence modulo $n$**. And what’s that?

> Let $a, b \in \mathbb{Z}$. We say that **$a$ is congruent with $b$ modulo $n$**, and denote $a \equiv b \pmod{n}$ if there’s an integer $k$ such that $a - b = n \cdot k$.

One intuitive idea for doing this is thinking that each number is always congruent with “any” *rest* that comes from the integer division of $a$ by $n$.

Some examples are: $2 \equiv 0 \pmod{2}$, $6 \equiv 0 \pmod{3}$, ...

In order to get $2 + 2 = 5$ (And for that $4 = 5$) we consider that $4 \equiv 5 \pmod{1}$ [Since $4-5=(-1)=(-1)\cdot 1$]. And with this you get all kind of that operations.

Comment: Would it work as well if I construct a group with a shifted addition table? IMO, there shouldn't be any contradictions within that group. The neutral/inverse element would just be -1 instead of 0.

Answer (score 7):

For clarity, here are some definitions and properties of addition that I think you'll agree are very reasonable no matter what system of arithmetic you use.

- $2 = 1 + 1$ (a perfectly reasonable definition if you ask me), and $5 = 1 + 1 + 1 + 1 + 1$.
- If $x + 1 = y + 1$ then $x = y$. That is, if two piles of stones are the same size, you can remove a stone from each and they're still the same size.
- $(a + b) + c$ is equal to $a + (b + c)$. That is, we can divide a pile of stones into two sub-piles, and move one of the sub-piles to another pile, without changing the total number of stones.
- If $a = b$ then $a + c = b + c$, and similarly for $c + a = c + b$. That is, if two piles of stones are the same size, you can swap them out for each other without changing the total number of stones.
- $0 + a = a + 0 = a$. That is, adding no stones to a pile keeps it the same size.

It is then the case that if $2 + 2 = 5$ then $0 = 1$.

And if $0 = 1$, then you can prove that *any* number expressible as a sum of $1$s is equal to any other number. Indeed, for example, $2 = 1 + 1 = 0 + 0 = 0$.

So number systems where the Extremely Reasonable properties above hold and also $0 = 1$ are not very interesting. (There is such a system - integers modulo $1$ - but it's only got one number in it.) You're going to have to drop one of the Extremely Reasonable properties if you want to make something more interesting happen, and then there's a good argument that you're not really talking about "numbers" any more - these "numbers" certainly won't let you count, for example.

Comment: Easier is to note that if $0=1$ then $0=0\cdot x = 1\cdot x =x$ - that also ensures that there's no numbers hanging out other than those writable as $1+1+1+\ldots+1$. Also probably worth noting that an example of such a number system is integer arithmetic mod $1$, as the OP mentioned modular arithemetic.

Comment: @MiloBrandt I want to stay away from multiplication because it's less obvious what it means to multiply piles of stones. Thanks for the suggestions; I've clarified "any number expressible as a sum of $1$s".

Comment: @Patrick Stevens I found this on quora: https://www.quora.com/How-can-0-1-1/answer/Bill-Shillito -- What do you think? My mathematical understanding is to limited to understand the answer by Bill Shillito.

Comment: In general if you've got a sufficiently nice structure, like the integers, you can get another nice structure by saying "I'll stop distinguishing between certain things" (for a sufficiently nice "certain"). For example, if we stop distinguishing between even numbers, then we end up with another nice structure that has just two things in: "odd" and "even" (or "numbers like $1$" and "numbers like "$0$"). If we stop distinguishing between numbers that differ by a multiple of $3$, then we get a nice structure with three things in: "numbers like $0$", "numbers like $1$", and "numbers like $2$".

Comment: If we stop distinguishing between numbers that differ by a multiple of $1$, then we get a nice structure with only one thing in, because all numbers already differ by a multiple of $1$. That's the number system "integers mod $1$", and it has exactly one member. The integers mod $n$ obey most of the same rules as the integers do, which is why I'm justified in calling them "nice".

Answer (score 1):

The point about modular arithmetic really refers to the [coset sum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coset#Integers)

$$ (n\mathbb{Z} + 2) + (n\mathbb{Z} + 2) = (n\mathbb{Z} + 5) $$

for $n = 1$, not $2 + 2 = 5$. In this case, "$k$" really refers to $n\mathbb{Z} + k$, not $k$.